# How to generate TimeStamp of particular specific time

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

How can we generate TimeStamp of any particular selected time.
Suppose I selected any date and time say "13/03/2019  01:11:14" so how can I generate the timestamp of that particular time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let selectedDate = "13/03/2019 01:11:14"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:selectedDate)!

let timestamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add "print(addDate(selectDate: "13/03/2019 01:11:14"))" this line in view didload And Add "addDate" function in file. Also Check Attach Image.
Print Output and online site both are same.

```
func addDate(selectDate:String) -> Double
{
    let dFormat = DateFormatter()
    dFormat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dFormat.date(from:selectDate)!
    let timeStamp = date.timeIntervalSince1970
    return timeStamp
}
```

[image: check Image]